# How can I rewrite this program with a while loop instead of a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

Write a loop to print the powers of 3 under 10,000 (it should
print 3, 9, 27, etc.).
Rewrite this loop with a while loop. (Hint: Provide the
setup before the loop.)

For loop I created:

```
for (var x = 3; x < 10000; x = x * 3) {
  alert(x);
}
```

I am stuck, I know I need to set the conditions before the loop, but I'm getting nowhere

Comment: var x = 3; while (x < 10000) { alert(x); x *= 3;}

Comment: in general ... `for(i;c;p) { b }` => `i; while(c) { b; p;}`

Comment: `I need to set the conditions before the loop` no, you need to set the "setup before the loop" - it says so right there in your homework question

Comment: `alert` is usually not what is meant when someone says "print"; try `console.log()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Generally speaking, it is customary to include some examples of what you yourself have tried in your posts.  A common refrain in the comments on this site is that "Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service."  That sounds harsh, and I understand that that was not your intention-- you are simply stuck and looking for help.  However, you need to show you have done your own due diligence in trying to resolve a problem before raising it here-- particularly for homework questions.  Take a look at [ask], then maybe revisit this post and see if it can be salvaged.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var x=3;
 while(x< 10000)
 {
      console.log(×);
      x=x*3;
 }
```

alert blocks the code execution until alert is removed. To print you can use console.log.